# Does large difference between PrivateBytes vs BytesInAllHeaps definitily indicate unmanaged memory leak?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks

My 32-bit process is throwing OutOfMemoryException.

When this happens the perfmon counters for the process say:

- Process - PrivateBytes: ~2000MB
- .Net - BytesInAllHeaps: ~500MB

My process does interop with unmanaged code but my question is, does the size ratio definitely indicate an unmanaged memory leak?

Comment: Depends on what you're doing. Maybe the memory is actually used. It is hard to say not knowing what the program does.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.  BTW ... you only have about 1.6GB of available memory in a win32 process.  32-bit architecture can address 4GB of RAM.  Top 2GB is used reserved ... leaving your application with about 1.6GB max.  Try switching to 64-bit code.